# Node.JS: Getting error : [nodemon] Internal watch failed: watch ENOSPC

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just installed `Node.js` on my `Ubuntu 14.04` operating system for the first time. I also installed `npm`. The next step in my installation process was installing `nodemon`. This all worked out fine.

---

***But, when I run `nodemon` by typing `nodemon app.js` in my command line, I get the following error...***

`[nodemon] 1.8.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter`rs
`[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting`node app.js
`[nodemon] Internal watch failed: watch ENOSPC`

***In the command line below the error...***

```
alopex@Alopex:~/Desktop/coding_dojo/week-9/javascript/node/testing_node$ Hello World
```

Why is this happening? Is this normal behavior for nodemon? If not, how can I fix it?

---

***Side notes...***

1) `app.js` is a `Javascript` file with `console.log(111)` inside of it.
2) `node` version is `v0.10.25`
3) `npm` version is `1.3.10`
4) `nodemon` version is `1.8.1`
5) `ubuntu` version is...

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grunt watch error - Waiting...Fatal error: watch ENOSPC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748737/grunt-watch-error-waiting-fatal-error-watch-enospc)

Answer (score 573, accepted):

It appears that my max ports weren't configured correctly.
Here is the fix.

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=582222 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

What this command does is to increase the number of watches allowed for a single user. By the default the number can be low (8192 for example). When `nodemon` tries to watch large numbers of directories for changes it has to create several watches, which can surpass that limit.

More explanation of how it solves the problem:
`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` it increase the number of watches of nodemon as you made some changes in your project and
`sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p is sysctl` command for configure kernel parameters at runtime.
More on https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/kernel_parameters

You could also solve this problem by:

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=582222 && sudo sysctl -p
```

But the way it was written first will make this change permanent.

Comment: Could someone explain a little more what this does and elaborate on why it could help?

Comment: @Hinrich, it is just a guess, i think nodejs watches the file system changes via inotify library. I think there is a limit per user for the max number of watches, which this setting changes to a greater value.

Comment: @devrimbaris Correct!

Comment: It has just happened to me after going from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04. Your solution worked for me as well. Thank you

Comment: I have to run this every time I restart my machine. Can someone tell me how to avoid running it every time I restart?

Comment: Works on CentOS 7

Comment: Put that on `/etc/sysctl.d/90-override.conf` if you're on Arch

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49363821/2157459 if you don't want to mess with system configurations

Comment: Downvote for not providing description what your code mean

Comment: It helps. Ubuntu 18.04, Nodemon. Thank you.

Comment: elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki, Nodemon 1.17.5, Node 8.11.2, worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=582222 && sudo sysctl -p worked for me. Mine is a Linux Mint version OS.

Comment: Or just try to close Atom or any other program that watch a lot of files.

Comment: Issue fixed by below command echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p for Ubuntu bydefault limit is set to 8192. We need to increase this.

Comment: great this solution is working fine for me.......I have got same error but now solved....Thanks!

Comment: This does worked for me thank you                                                                                                                          `sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=582222 && sudo sysctl -p`

Comment: Read this if you want very clear explanations of the command https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc

Comment: This is killer!!

Answer (score 53):

### On running node server shows Following Errors and solutions:

nodemon server.js

> [nodemon] 1.17.2
>
> [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
>
> [nodemon] watching: *.*
>
> [nodemon] starting `node server.js`

### [nodemon] Internal watch failed: watch /home/aurum304/jin ENOSPC

```
sudo pkill -f node
```

### or

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: Be careful with the 'sudo pkill -f node' command. It force kills all running node applications. Some apps (e.g. Atom, vscode) depend on node and therefore this command could potentially crash those apps and you could lose work. Also it is not guaranteed to have effect anyway. Second one is better.

Answer (score 33):

Erik,
You can just kill all the other node processes by

> pkill -f node

and then restart your server again. It'll work just fine then.

Comment: Downvote because this also caused my Visual Studio Code windows to freeze.

Comment: this was working like a charm...until now!
Now its ineffective, getting same error.

Comment: If you have multiple things running with node, this will cause them all to stop.  This is especially troublesome if you have both a client and server running.

Comment: This isn't an answer, this is a comment

Comment: This is useful only to run in a isolate environment like dedicated node docker

Answer (score 26):

As per discussion over [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/214), `ENOSPC` means `Error No more hard-disk space available`. Reason why this much memory required by `nodemon` or `gulp-nodemon` (in my case) is that it was watching contents of a folder which it shouldn't. To fix that nodemon has `ignore` setting that can be used to tell nodemon what not to watch. Have a look at nodemon sample config [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/sample-nodemon.md).

Comment: Good job, this is the root cause.

Comment: This was the reason for me. Spot on explanation of ENOSPC. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

```
[nodemon] Internal watch failed: watch /home/Document/nmmExpressServer/bin ENOSPC
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nmmexpressserver@0.0.0 start: `nodemon ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nmmexpressserver@0.0.0 start script.
```

This is the error I got when running `nodemon ./bin/www`.

> **The solution was closing an Atom window** that had a entire directory of folders open in the project window.

I don't know why, but I'm assuming Atom and nodemon use similar processes to watch files/folders.

Comment: That was exactly my problem. I happeed to launch atom from the project's install directory. I closed atom, launched it from a different dir and the problem went away.

Comment: In my case, the same was happening on Sublime in Ubuntu. When I closed the IDE, I could run it properly. Any tips about it?

Comment: I've not tried to replicate it to see if it has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Mine can work after I close Gitkraken. This is a strange problem. So that means we can not have two processes monitoring the same folder?

Comment: It was Nextcloud client here - that uses a ton of inotify watches.  Thanks, y'all!

Comment: At my is case was sublime editor running. I closed it and everything works fine.

Answer (score 12):

Add a `nodemon.json` configuration file in your root folder and specify ignore patterns for example:

`nodemon.json`

```
{
  "ignore": [
    "*.test.js", 
    "dist/*"
  ]
}
```

- Note that by default `.git`, `node_modules`, `bower_components`, `.nyc_output`, `coverage` and `.sass-cache` are ignored so you don't need to add them to your configuration.

Explanation: This error happens because you exceeded the max number of watchers allowed by your system (i.e. `nodemon` has no more disk space to watch all the files - which probably means you are watching not important files). So you ignore non-important files that you don't care about changes in them for example the build output or the test cases.

Answer (score 6):

in my case closing the visual studio code then starting the server did the trick

Operating system - ubuntu 16.4 lts

node.js version - 8.11.1

npm version - 6.0.0

Comment: It seems that he was not using visual studio.

Comment: Although this doesn't directly answer the question (because the question doesn't involve VS Code), this did solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks, just simple, It solved my problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of specifying a list of directories to ignore (e.g. negative), you can also specify a list of directories to watch (e.g positive):

```
nodemon --watch dir1 --watch dir2  dir1/examples/index.js
```

In my particular case, I had one directory I wanted to watch and about nine I wanted to ignore, so specifying '--watch' was much simpler than specifying '--ignore'

Comment: Thanks, my nodemon was restarting multiple times in a docker container and taking forever to reload the server. Added the watch for my src folder and it's lightning fast.

Answer (score 2):

**There must be a better way of solving this, than what I suggest. I hope some experts land on this page. Also note that I was working on a development server and thus could afford to kill all processes of node. This may not be what you want.**

I followed the answer of [@zubair-alam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39355380/7480460)  and got it fixed for the first time. I added the "ignore" to the package.json (Even though the referred link says it is the default).

```json
 ........ Before
  "ignore": [
    ".git",
    "node_modules/**/node_modules"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon ./index.js --exec babel-node -e js"
  },
 ........ After
```

However the error returned again as soon as I added a new file to the folder. I was working on Linux, so I basically killed all process related to node, by saying the following.

```sh
killall node
```

and then restarted npm by saying. The server started without errors.

```sh
npm start
```

You will have to change the killall command using a command specific to your operating system. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14790921/7480460) discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but in Ubuntu 14.04 inside Windows 10 (Bash on Ubuntu on Windows). All I did to overcome the error was to update the Creators update, which then allowed me to install 16.04 version of Ubuntu bash and then after installing newest version of node (by [this](https://aigeec.com/installing-node-js-on-windows-10-bash/) steps) I installed also the newest version of npm and then the nodemon started to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try reopening VS code or Atom with more **specific directory** where your app.js is present.
I had a lot of folders opened and this problem occured. But once I opened my specific folder and tried once again, it worked.