# Nodemon not working after updating to version 1.18.10

Tags: node.js, nodemon

`nodemon` was working perfectly in my mac previously, I updated it to the latest version and when I try to start it, I keep getting the below error.

Error:

```
[nodemon] Internal watch failed: errmap.get is not a function or its return value is not iterable
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but the error doesn't seem to go.

Anyone facing a similar issue with `nodemon` on mac?

Comment: Looks like a bug in `nodemon`. Try installing the previous version: `npm i nodemon@1.18.9`

Comment: @robertklep same error

Comment: Tried going back to previously working version `1.18.3` and got the same error

Comment: Follow the steps from it [Follow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662574/node-js-getting-error-nodemon-internal-watch-failed-watch-enospc)

Comment: There are various bug reports for this error ([here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1499) and [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1512)). There doesn't seem to be a single solution. Are you sure that you're starting the correct version of `nodemon`? Try running `nodemon --version` (as the user that also run it in your regular setup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after trying different solutions, I updated my node version from 10.x to 11.x and it worked.