# Node.JS [nodemon] Internal watch failed: ENFILE: file table overflow

Tags: node.js, macos, node-modules

```
[nodemon] 1.19.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: src/**/*
[nodemon] starting `ts-node index.ts`
[nodemon] Internal watch failed: ENFILE: file table overflow
```

I tried killing node process, and also tried running

`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

I get

```
sysctl: illegal option -- p
usage: sysctl [-bdehiNnoqx] name[=value] ...
       sysctl [-bdehNnoqx] -a
```

But these doesn't seem to work. I'm using macOS 10.15.3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51759469/5751251 Maybe that will help?

Comment: I'm not getting `ENOSPC` error. So sadly it didn't help :(

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem.

sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 65536 200000

worked for me. Found it here: https://wilsonmar.github.io/maximum-limits/

Answer (score 1):

You need to  limit the number of files and processes that are allowed to be open. This limit protects the system from being overrun.

Run

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 65536 200000
```